# Yii Jquery AJAX Call not firing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii, call

I have been researching and trying to learn the proper method to accomplish this. I have done the following but, I still have no change on my form. Is there anyway to see if the ajax call is even being made? Could anyone correct this code to figure out why I am not getting any change on the field in my form.

In my model I have the following function

```
     public function standardRate($country) 
    { 

    $country_std_rate = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()       
       ->select('AVG(rate_syr_mh)')       
       ->from('packaging_metrics')       
       ->where(array('like', 'country', '%'.$country.'%'))    
       ->queryRow();    

            echo CJSON::encode($country_std_rate);  

    }
```

In my controller I have added this function as well as added 'countryRate' to my access control for all

```
public function countryRate() 
    { 
            $input_country = $_POST['country']; 

            $model = PackagingMetric::model()->standardRate($input_country); 
            echo CJSON::encode($model);  

            Yii::app()->end(); 

            $this->render('countryRate',array( 
                    'model'=>$model, 
            )); 

    }
```

This is my Jquery call in my form

```
  $('#PackagingMetric_std_rate').live('click',function() 
    {  

 var country =  $('#country').val();  

       $.ajax({  
               type: 'POST',  
               url: 'PackagingMetric/countryRate',  
               data: {country:country},  

                           success: function(data)  
                               {                                                      

                $('#PackagingMetric_std_rate').html(data); 

               } 

                               }); 

             });
```

However, nothing on my form changes with a value, I am using Yii-Debug-toolbar and not seeing any POST calls or any sql queries upon clicking the appropriate field on my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `url` parameter for the `$.ajax();` <strike>is wrong</strike> could be wrong.

That is if you are not hiding the entry script (*index.php*), you will have to write:

```
url: 'index.php/controllername/actionname'
```

instead of:

```
url: 'controllername/actionname'
```

It would be better to use [`createUrl()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail):

```
url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('PackagingMetric/countryRate'); ?>'
```

(Ofcourse the `echo` above and how you include php code in js will depend on how you are including the js in the first place)

And name your countryRate as `actionCountryRate()`.

Comment: Thanks, however I am getting this error Property "PackagingMetricController.createUrl" is not defined. 

which is strange because I believe this function should extend from the main controller?

Comment: Yes I believe so, this line is at the top of my class class PackagingMetricController extends Controller

Comment: you can also use `Yii::app()->createUrl()` in the meantime.

Comment: url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('PackagingMetric/countryRate'); ?>' , 
This sould work to my understanding, but for some reason there is some syntax error I am unable to locate, it seems to disabling the Jquery for the rest of my form

Comment: hmm, how are you including this script?

Comment: It is the last of a series of events for several input fields on my form. It is included at the top of my _form view file in this manner Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('packaging_metric_formvalid1', " ....code... ");

Comment: if you are using registerScript, then don't use `<?php ?>`! , then you just use `url: '".Yii::app()->createUrl('whatever')."'` . if you using `registerScript(''," ")`, i.e if you are using  double quotes to include your script code, use this way. this is string concatenation.

Comment: This appears to fix that issue! However, I still am getting no change on my form :(

Comment: atleast post(url call) is happening? i.e ajax call firing?

Comment: I take that back!!! I am getting the folllowing put into my input! when I switch  this to put .val instead of .html I get $('#PackagingMetric_std_rate').val(data);
This appears in my field which seems to be generating the value  {"AVG(rate_syr_mh)":"23.2857"}null I need the number, but how do I remove everything else but the value ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14087/discussion-between-bool-dev-and-user1496306)

Answer (score 2):

Rename the function in the controller to actionCountryRate()

When a post request is made to a controller, it looks for an action using the action prefix.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize this was a strict Yii convention. And for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

I consider to use absolute url while firing an ajax call.
Try to make your url in this way, it will solve your problem.

```
url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('PackagingMetric/countryRate');           ?>',
```

and your controller action name should be "actionCountryRate" because this function is hit from url, not internally called from controller, also set its accessRule if you are using access control otherwise the function will not execution.